# how can I load a variable in sass that is in memory? when I import the sass file I get: "SassError: This file is already being loaded"

Tags: reactjs

Iam using gatsby with the following `gatsby-plugin-sass` with this configuration:

```
{
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    options: {
        additionalData: '@import "utils/_index.scss";',   //***this contains***: @import 'variables';
        sassOptions: {
           includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/scss')],
        }
    },
},
```

(everything is set up correctly to read my `.scss` files and that includes  `_variables.scss` )

I have a file called: `_variables.scss`

```
$color-black: #000000;
```

In my component I have:

```
import * as scss from '../../assets/scss/utils/_variables.scss';
```

I am doing:

```
console.log(scss)
```

And I am getting this error:

```
SassError: This file is already being loaded.   │ @import 'variables';
```

how to get the variables from `_variables.scss` even though the file has already been loaded?